# Problems with a sentence in mysql with java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm developing a program with java where I have some sql sentences, this one:

```
SQL="SELECT t0.id_proveedor_cloud as id_proveedor_cloud,";
SQL.concat("t1.id_procesador as id_procesador,");
SQL.concat("t2.id_tarea as id_tarea,");
SQL.concat("DATE_FORMAT(t2.f_ultima_ejecucion,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') as f_ultima_ejecucion,");
SQL.concat("t3.id_esquema_asociado as id_esquema_asociado,");
SQL.concat("t3.descripcion as descripcion_esquema,");
SQL.concat("t3.cadena_conexion_sql as cadena_conexion_sql,");
SQL.concat("t3.url_portal_ccis as url_portal_ccis");
SQL.concat("FROM proveedores_cloud t0");
SQL.concat("INNER JOIN procesadores t1 ON t1.id_proveedor_cloud=t0.id_proveedor_cloud");
SQL.concat("INNER JOIN tareas t2 ON t2.id_procesador = t1.id_procesador");
SQL.concat("INNER JOIN esquemas_asociados t3 ON t3.id_proveedor_cloud=t0.id_proveedor_cloud");
SQL.concat("WHERE t0.id_proveedor_cloud =1");
SQL.concat("AND t1.activo = true");
SQL.concat("AND t2.activa = true");
SQL.concat("AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t2.f_ultima_ejecucion,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) >= t2.iniciar_cada)");
SQL.concat("ORDER BY t0.id_proveedor_cloud,t2.orden");
```

When I try to execute it with my program in Java I have a mistake near `INNER JOIN procesadores t1 ON t1.id_proveedor_cloud=t0.id_proveedor_cloud` but when I execute this query on my Navicat, I don't have any mistake, where is the mistake, where is the problem?

Comment: Where are your spaces? e.G. between t0 and INNER JOIN?

Comment: You have all the reason, I have eaten all of them.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @eggyal probably a not so bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the spaces in your query.

For example here

```
SQL.concat("FROM proveedores_cloud t0");
SQL.concat("INNER JOIN procesadores t1 ON t1.id_proveedor_cloud=t0.id_proveedor_cloud");
```

This will yield to this string:

`FROM proveedores_cloud t0INNER JOIN procesadores t1 ON t1.id_proveedor_cloud=t0.id_proveedor_cloud`

Which is no valid `SQL` and can't be parsed by the query parser.

See the javadoc example for `String#concat`:

```
 "cares".concat("s") returns "caress"
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)

You can simply fix it, by adding a space at the end of your concats, for example after your `FROM` clause:

```
SQL.concat("t3.url_portal_ccis as url_portal_ccis ");
SQL.concat("FROM proveedores_cloud t0 ");
SQL.concat("INNER JOIN procesadores t1 ON t1.id_proveedor_cloud=t0.id_proveedor_cloud ");
SQL.concat("INNER JOIN tareas t2 ON t2.id_procesador = t1.id_procesador ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing blanks in the string created in Java. In Navicat you have linefeeds between each line but that whitespace is missing in the string you built in Java.

Some part of your string is

```
...FROM proveedores_cloud t0INNER JOIN procesadores...
```

Add spaces at the end handles it

```
...
SQL.concat("FROM proveedores_cloud t0 ");
...
```

You need to do that basically for all the lines not ending on a comma